# The method 'fromDocument' isn't defined for the type 'User'. (undefined_method )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

> i tried to make a user instance in Document snapshot using the below code but when i import user.dart and call the  "user.fromDocument(docs)" it showing an error that the method fromDocument isn't defined for the type user

```
class user {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String occupation;
  final String email;
  final String description;


  user(
      {this.id,
      this.username,
      this.occupation,
      this.email,
      this.description,
      });

  factory user.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return user(
        id: doc['id'],
        email: doc['email'],
        occupation: doc['occupation'],
        photourl: doc['photoUrl'],
        description: doc['description'],
        username: doc['displayName']);
  }
}
createUserInFirestore() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();
if (!doc.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (Context) => CreateAccount()));

usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "Occupation": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "description": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
      usersRef.doc(user.id).get();
    } else if (doc.exists) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
    }

    **currentUser = user.fromDocument(doc);**
    print(currentUser);
    print(currentUser.username);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the user referred bellow is the instance of GoogleSignInAccount defined on top and not instance of your class user, look this line of your code:

```
final GoogleSignInAccount user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved by
changing the name of the class user to GUser or UserG or whatever you want.
for example
class Guser